# Background image and a border-top element not displaying correctly on mobile devices

Tags: image, css, mobile, background, cover

I've spent an entire day struggling with an issue that has occurred with mobile devices such as *iPhones*, *iPads* and an *Acer tablet*. I haven't been able to check with other devices but the problem seems to be quite universal when it comes to mobile devices.

Here are the first three css elements I use:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#page-wrap {
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The point here being that I have a bunch of 1200 pixel-wide `<div>` elements with content placed inside other, browser-wide elements. So, first, I use css to make my site use all of the browser window and then add `<div>` elements like this one and center them:

```
#featured {
    background: #282828;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    }
    #featured #inside {
        background: #282828 repeat;
        width: 1200px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    }
```

**And here's the issue:**

I'm currently using this code to define a fixed position background image for a `<div>` element:

```
#banner_index {
    background: url(../images/banner/index.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 2000px 1333px;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

While this makes the background look perfectly fine on all the necessary desktop browsers, all the forementioned mobile devices (regardless of the browser app used) display the background image smaller, ie. not completely stretched out to fill the `<div>` element.

More to my demise, I've created a header `<div>` for the site above the `#banner_index` element, which has a top border of 3 pixels. Here's the code for that one:

```
#header {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-top: solid #282828 3px;
}
```

Much to my surprise, this border, and in fact the whole `<div>` seems to be sliced to the same width as the background image on the `#banner_index` element right below it.

I realize that mobile devices have problems with the `fixed` code in the `background:` element but all the workarounds I've managed to find seem to be of no use. Especially when the `border-top:` element has nothing to do with background images.

***Anyone care to help a frustrated enthusiast out?***

I'd like to keep my site Javascript-free and thought maybe a more simple css solution is out there.

***Therein lies the rub.***

Comment: Can you show us a live example?

Comment: Welcome on SO. It would be easier to help you with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue. Also you didn't mention which mobile browser are you using, and your html structure. BTW +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks! @3rror404, here's a live example: [Obscure Entertainment](http://obscure.fi). I didn't have time to make a Fiddle yesterday but the mobile browsers used were Chrome and Safari. Others may have been used as well but which ones, I don't know. We received some feedback on the site from friends as well.